# LaTeX table of contents header spacing

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, memoir

Here is my issue. The code below, which I found on a pdf devoted to memoir class title pages, compiles to form this:

[image]

Unfortunately, the Table of Contents is a bit too low for my liking. I'm hoping its an easy fix to figure out the, maybe, header spacing?...Although the header isn't mentioned anywhere in the code.  I was hoping to fit the ToC all on one page.

```
%title page environment
\newcommand*{\titleSI}{\begingroup% Sagas
\drop = 0.025\textheight
\centering
\vspace*{\drop}
{\Huge EXCERPTS}\\[\baselineskip]
{\Huge \itshape{from}}\\[\baselineskip]
{\Huge THE LETTERS OF}\\[\baselineskip]
{\Huge EARNEST A. RAYMOND}\\[\baselineskip]
{\Huge \itshape{to}}\\[\baselineskip]
{\Huge HIS CHILDREN}\\[3\baselineskip]
{\Large \textit{Arranged by} \textsc{Sarah Raymond Dean}}\\
{\Large \textit{Digitized by} \textsc{John Maxwell Dunn}}\par
\vspace*{\drop}
{\Large Written 1932 - Digitized 2014}\\[\baselineskip]
\endgroup}

\begin{document}
% Title Page
\titleSI

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Success}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question. See if this related (duplicate?) question helps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44751/

Answer (score 1):

Set `\cftbeforechapskip` to a smaller and possibly stretchable value. (not quite sure if I spelled it correctly. It controls the spacing above chapter entries in the toc. Also you might want to use `\tableofcontents*` as it will not add it self to the toc.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
\begingroup
\baselineskip=1pt
\tableofcontents
\endgroup
```

or

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\enlargethispage{1.5\normalbaselineskip}}
```

which enlarges the contentspage.